# Site has been hacked with popup injection

Tags: wordpress, code-injection

Can someone help me with this annoying popup injection? I am a Senior UX Designer and I know a lot about css and maybe a little javascript. I know that the injection leads me to

```
<script src="https://poponclick.info/click.js"></script>
```

I just can't find it!

http://renardrichie.com/blog/

It basically hits everything underneath that folder.

I highly appreciate it. If you guys find it

I will probably download the entire site and will just delete all the injection codes.

Comment: We can't really help - if your WP site is infected with malware, it could be *anywhere* (plugins, theme, core WP files, the database, etc). This is also just part of the reason it is also very difficult to clean an infected WP site, and it can just keep getting reinfected. Your safest option is to restore the last clean backup you have.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I don't remember if i ever make a clean backup haha. But worst come to worst i can just download everything and then delete everything on that path including wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded the site to php 5.6
Upgraded wordpress to 5.4.2

injection no longer exist. I think the php upgrade killed the injection.

I also subscribe to sucuri's malware removal subscription. They currently scrubbing the site to remove potential malwares.

Thank you for the help @fluffykitten